# Change font size relative to previous class

Tags: html, css

I have this component that accepts any classname. To this I wish to add another class what would make the item smaller by a % say 90%. How do I achieve that.

```html
<span class="specified_class my_added_class" ></span>
```

Problem is my class replaces existing class's font size(which is expected). Instead I want it to take that into account.

I thought of using transform:scale to achieve same but It won't work on inline elements and I cant make it inline-block

Comment: You will add that class on button click? page load?

Comment: neither on a react component load

Comment: in this case you need to get the existing font-size and multiply it with 0.9 and reapply on your new class,

Comment: how can I do it in css. I don't want to use JS

Comment: @aWebDeveloper So for example, you will have font-size 20px for the class 'specified_class'. You want it to become 18px when you add a class 'my_added_class' ? Is that the req ? How is the second class getting added

Comment: I don't think the result you want is possible with CSS only., yes it is possible if only you provide the font size to each class manually

Comment: @aWebDeveloper You can use variables I guess ?

Comment: @JithinB yes that's what I want and no I cant use variables

Answer (score 0):

I would use the unit `em` in this situation. em is a relative unit, which 1em means use the current font-size set by my closest parent. You can use this in your component so that the passed in prop acts like a multiplier.

### NO JS Solution

```html
<style>
.specified_class {
font-size: 10px; // Controles the size
}

.sz-default{
  font-size: 1.0em
}

.sz-third{
  font-size: .3em;
}

.sz-half{
  font-size: .5em;
}

.sz-double{
  font-size: 2em;
}

.sz-triple{
  font-size: 3em;
}
</style>
<span class="specified_class sz-triple">I am 30px</span><br>
<span class="specified_class sz-double">I am 20px</span><br>
<span class="specified_class sz-default">I am 10px</span><br>
<span class="specified_class sz-half">I am 5px</span>
```

### React Solution

1. First, set the em value

Wrap the html in another div tag and add inline styles forcing its pixel size to 0.1px.

2. Use the prop to set font-size

Now in your template, you can pass in props which will be used change the font-size.
(don't forget to set a default value encase you forget to pass in the prop.

### Example

```
export const myTemplate = props => {

const default = "100em"; // sets default font-size to 10px.

const size = {font-size: `${props.size}em`} || default;

return(
  <div style={{font-size: "0.1px"}}>
    <span class="specified_class" style=size></span> 
  </div> 
 )
}

export const myTemplate
```

Comment: Your example is not working css one. 

https://imgur.com/a/9DIlz1d

Comment: I am not 100% sure why this is not working but working in the above code snippet. Could you put your code in something we could see like codepen and send us the link to investigate?

Comment: inspect element your result from Run code and see computed style